# HTML 5 Drag Drop - Get the drop location of dragged element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a widget, where you drag an element to a container.
I want to get the dragged elements top left corner location on drop, but instead the `event.offsetY` returns the mouse location.

I have also tried `layerY` but this is not right.

```
dropped(e) {
  console.log('dropped at', e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

Is there a simple way of getting it or a library i can use?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out where your mouse is relative to your element when you *first start dragging it*. Do this by comparing the initial `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` to the **page**;

Take the *elements* `offsetX` and `offsetY` away from the *mouse's* `offsetX` and `offsetY`. This might tell you you started dragging at a position of 50px by 60px from the top left of the element;

```
let initialPos = {
  x: e.offsetX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
  y: e.offsetY - element.getBoundingClientRect().top
}
```

[image]

You can then use this `50px 60px` position when you drop the element to find out where the top left of the element is relative to your mouse.

Comment: How can I get the element?

Comment: @Ana Add an ID to the element and use the usual getElementByID.